# Plotly: tick label range - hide ticks with negative values

Tags: python, plotly

I feel like I've tried everything, but I cannot find a way to hide negative tick labels in Python Plotly. Is there any way to do that?

I like the default ticks in general because they react nicely to changes in the data and with zoom in, however I sometimes have data that never goes under 0 - I would like to keep X axis range that goes into negative for some visibility (instead of clustering points in the chart near the edge), but want to hide the ticks like -5, -10 etc.

I know I can set tick0 and dtick to make my own ticks, but it's more complicated in my case because I'm changing variables with ipywidgets so it keeps changing and I like the default ticks otherwise

Comment: show the code that you have or at least a working example.

Comment: `N = 1000
t = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.sin(t)

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=t, y=y, mode='markers'))
fig.layout.xaxis.range = [-5, 11]
fig.show()`

Can;t seem to be able to add a picture here, but from above code, I would like to be able to see that chart with applied range, but without negative tick labels and without completely custom ticks so that:
A) it works well when zooming in
B) Ticks are by default recalculated when I change the data:

`fig.data[0]['x'] = list(np.arange(start=150, stop= 900, step=25))
fig.layout.xaxis.range = [-100, 1000]
fig.show()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- using your code from comment
- simple case of define **tickvals** and **ticktext** from the range you have defined. Granted stepSize is not automated

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

N = 1000 
t = np.linspace(0, 10, 100) 
y = np.sin(t)  
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=t, y=y, mode='markers')) 
fig.layout.xaxis.range = [-5, 11] 
stepSize = 2
r = range(fig.layout["xaxis"]["range"][0], fig.layout["xaxis"]["range"][1], stepSize)
fig.update_layout(xaxis={"tickvals":list(r),
                        "ticktext":[t if t>=0 else '' for t in r]})
```

Comment: Hey, sorry that I didn't reply earlier, but I was out of town last 2 days.
This helps a lot! Indeed seems like the best solution.